# Using SQL Bulkcopy based on Db contexts connection

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ado.net, sqlbulkcopy

In my .NET Core project (.NET 5) I'm using EF Core 6 and for SQL auth, it's using Azure AD Identity authentication.

Here is my startup where DB context is initialized:

```
services.AddDbContext<EPMO_DevContext>((provider, options) => //managed 
        {
            SqlConnection azureConnection = new SqlConnection(Configuration["DefaultConnection"]);
            var dbAuthentication = provider.GetService<Func<string, AzAuthentication>>()("DbScope");
            azureConnection.AccessToken = dbAuthentication?.AccessToken;

            SqlConnection localDb = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EpmoDb"));

            var tokenResult =  app.GetAuthenticationResultAsync(  Configuration["DbScope"] , "mydomain.com").Result;
            azureConnection.AccessToken = tokenResult.AccessToken;*/
           
            string env = Configuration["Environment"];

            options.UseSqlServer(env == "local" ? localDb:azureConnection, sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
            {
                sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                maxRetryCount: 10,
                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                errorNumbersToAdd: null);
            });
        });
```

And using DI in my constructor

```
public AdoExtract(IConfiguration configuration = null, EPMO_DevContext context = null)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    _context = context;
}
```

But since EF taking too much time for bulk insert I am advised to use SQL bulk copy

```
    private int WorkitemsToDb(List<AdoWorkitem> list )
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = _context.Database.GetDbConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
                {
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100;
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Person";
                    try
                    {
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(list.AsDataTable());
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

But at

```
SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Common.DbTransaction' to 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So how can I get the SQL connection in class for bulk copy when using EF and Azure AD authentication for SQL Server?

Comment: Why are you using that transaction in the first place? As for the error, it means you've mixed up the older `System.Data.SqlClient` with its replacement, `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` which is used by EF Core and most NuGet packages.  This has nothing to do with Azure AD

Comment: Could you please share the correct way. I am really sorry.. I was copying a legacy code.. (very old one)

Comment: SqlBulkCopy will use an internal transaction if you pass `SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction` to the constructor. You should still remove any references to the old `System.Data.SqlClient` though. BUT if you use a `BatchSize`, each batch will be executed in its own transaction. If you have a lot of data you *want* this, otherwise your transaction log will explode in size as it has to record everything and commit all rows in the end.

Comment: Could you please share that details in an answer.. I am only a beginner in that..

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't think that's what's going on here, it's simply that `GetDbConnection` returns a `DbConnection`, *that* should be cast to `SqlConnection`

Comment: Side note: `Rollback` is a waste of time, and you immediately follow with a `Commit` which will cause another exception, just let the `using` deal with it.

Comment: @Charlieface you're right. I focused on the namespaces